# What is the difference between @ModelAttribute and @SessionAttrubutes in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

i'm not able get clarity after browsing a while and visiting few sites. So please anyone explain me what exactly @ModelAttribute does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring API documentation is generally pretty good, so I would always recommend that as a starting point when trying to understand the framework.

The Javadocs for @ModelAttribute says the following:

> Annotation that binds a method parameter or method return value
>   to a named model attribute, exposed to a web view. Supported
>   for {@link RequestMapping} annotated handler classes.

Generally speaking, `@ModelAttribute` is a way for your controllers to declare methods whose return value is bound into the Model automatically by Spring, and to define Model values that are automatically bound into method parameters by Spring.

So for example:

```
@ModelAttribute("myValue")
public Foo myValue()
{
   return new MyFoo();
}
```

This essentially says to Spring:

> Whenever this Controller is mapped to service a request, call this method and bind the return value into the Model under the key "myValue".

This is the same as:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public ModelAndView foo()
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("myView");
    mav.addObject("myValue", new Foo());
    return mav;
}
```

There is no right and wrong approach here, it just facilitates a different way of building the Model.

The `@ModelAttribute` annotation can also be used on method parameters for your Controllers. So you could have the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/doFoo") 
public void doFoo(@ModelAttribute("myValue")Foo foo)
{
    Do some stuff here...
}
```

Again this is a convenient approach offering by Spring to facilitate different ways of implementing controllers. It is exactly the same as:

```
@RequestMapping("/doFoo") 
public void doFoo(ModelAndView modelAndView)
{
    Foo foo = (Foo)modelAndView.getModel().get("myValue");
    Do some stuff here...
}
```

`@SessionAttribute` works in exactly the same way, but as the name would suggest, the value is bound into or read from, the HTTPSession of the user rather than the Model.